# How can I change parameter value in XML using Perl?

Tags: xml, perl

My XML file looks like this:

```
<Configuration>
    <Parameters>
        <Component Name="Aas">
            <Group Name="PrivilegesMapping">
                <Parameter Name="PrivilegesLoaderInterval">
                    <Description>
                    The interval (in minute) 
                    </Description>
                    <Type>Integer</Type>
                    <Restriction>
                        <RequiresRestart>true</RequiresRestart>
                        <MinVal/>
                        <MaxVal/>
                        <MaxLength/>
                        <Mandatory>true</Mandatory>
                        <Lov/>
                        <Level>5</Level>
                    </Restriction>
                    <Value>
                        <Item Value="5"/>
                    </Value>
                </Parameter>
            </Group>
            <Group Name="DomainsMapping">
                <Parameter Name="DomainLoaderInterval">
                    <Description>
                    The interval (in minute) 
                    </Description>
                    <Type>Integer</Type>
                    <Restriction>
                        <RequiresRestart>true</RequiresRestart>
                        <MinVal/>
                        <MaxVal/>
                        <MaxLength/>
                        <Mandatory>true</Mandatory>
                        <Lov/>
                        <Level>5</Level>
                    </Restriction>
                    <Value>
                        <Item Value="5"/>
                    </Value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter Name="MapSource">
                    <Description>
                    Set the source of the domains list
                    </Description>
                    <Type>Enum</Type>
                    <Restriction>
                        <RequiresRestart>true</RequiresRestart>
                        <MinVal/>
                        <MaxVal/>
                        <MaxLength/>
                        <Mandatory>true</Mandatory>
                        <Lov>
                            <Val>FILE</Val>
                            <Val>DATABASE</Val>
                            <Val>NONE</Val>
                        </Lov>
                        <Level>5</Level>
                    </Restriction>
                    <Value>
                        <Item Value="FILE"/>
                    </Value>
                </Parameter>
            </Group>
            <Group Name="SystemsMapping">
                <Parameter Name="MapSource">
                    <Description>
                    </Description>
                    <Type>Enum</Type>
                    <Restriction>
                        <RequiresRestart>true</RequiresRestart>
                        <MinVal/>
                        <MaxVal/>
                        <MaxLength/>
                        <Mandatory>true</Mandatory>
                        <Lov>
                            <Val>API</Val>
                            <Val>FILE</Val>
                            <val>NONE</Val>
                        </Lov>
                        <Level>5</Level>
                    </Restriction>
                    <Value>
                        <Item Value="NONE"/>
                    </Value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter Name="SystemsLoaderInterval">
                    <Description>
                    The interval (in minute) 
                    </Description>
                    <Type>Integer</Type>
                    <Restriction>
                        <RequiresRestart>true</RequiresRestart>
                        <MinVal/>
                        <MaxVal/>
                        <MaxLength/>
                        <Mandatory>true</Mandatory>
                        <Lov/>
                        <Level>5</Level>
                    </Restriction>
                    <Value>
                        <Item Value="5"/>
                    </Value>
                </Parameter>
            </Group>
        </Component>
    </Parameters>
</Configuration>
```

I'd like to change value from `<Item Value="NONE"/>` to `<Item Value="API"/>` under `<Parameter Name="MapSource">`.

Comment: Do you have an XSLT processor available?  This is trivial in XSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remembering that processing XML with regular expressions is [usually a really bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), with Perl you could

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

system("xsltproc", "fix.xsl", "input.xml") == 0
  or warn "$0: xsltproc failed\n";
```

and with `fix.xsl` of

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Configuration/Parameters/Component/Group/Parameter[@Name='MapSource']/Value/Item[@Value='NONE']">
    <xsl:element name="Item">
      <xsl:attribute name="Value">API</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get the desired result:

```
$ diff -ub input.xml <(./prog.pl)
--- input.xml
+++ /dev/fd/63
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Configuration>
     <Parameters>
         <Component Name="Aas">
@@ -82,7 +83,7 @@
                         <Level>5</Level>
                     </Restriction>
                     <Value>
-                        <Item Value="NONE"/>
+                        <Item Value="API"/>
                     </Value>
                 </Parameter>
                 <Parameter Name="SystemsLoaderInterval">
```

In case you aren't familiar, `<(./prog.pl)` uses [bash process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), so the `diff` command is comparing `input.xml` with the *output* of the short Perl program.

To replace all Item elements that are descendants of MapSource parameters, use the stylesheet below. Note how it's more flexible about the structure of the source document.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//Parameter[@Name='MapSource']//Item">
    <xsl:element name="Item">
      <xsl:attribute name="Value">API</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now the change from input to output is

```
$ diff -ub input.xml <(./prog.pl)
--- input.xml
+++ /dev/fd/63
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Configuration>
     <Parameters>
         <Component Name="Aas">
@@ -59,7 +60,7 @@
                         <Level>5</Level>
                     </Restriction>
                     <Value>
-                        <Item Value="FILE"/>
+                        <Item Value="API"/>
                     </Value>
                 </Parameter>
             </Group>
@@ -82,7 +83,7 @@
                         <Level>5</Level>
                     </Restriction>
                     <Value>
-                        <Item Value="NONE"/>
+                        <Item Value="API"/>
                     </Value>
                 </Parameter>
                 <Parameter Name="SystemsLoaderInterval">
```

Comment: I loved this solution. Thank you. 
Q: How I can change the fix.xsl to avoid use 'NONE' in path [@Value='NONE'] . I do not want care what string currently occupied <Item Value >

Answer (score 0):

The quickest (easiest) way I found was [`XML::XPath`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::XPath) (even smaller with [`File::Slurp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Slurp) -- see edit history for pre-slurp code):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp ();
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

my $path = '/path/to/file/config.xml';
my $xp   = XML::XPath->new( filename => $path );
$xp->setNodeText( q{//Parameter[@Name='MapSource']/Value/Item/@Value} 
                , 'API'
                );
File::Slurp::write_file( $path, $xp->findnodes_as_string( '/' ));
```